# Windows credential provider logging

Tags: c++, windows, credential-providers

I am simply looking to add logging output to a file in a Windows credential provider v2, I am not sure on the best way to achieve it.

I am also looking to run a loop within Credential provider to check if a file exists but unsure where to start the function from?

Answer (score 0):

To monitor for some system Hardware have a look at [SampleHardwareEventCredentialProvider](https://github.com/alexyack/CredentialProviders/tree/master/SampleHardwareEventCredentialProvider).

To log something you can always use system event log in two simple calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you develop it using Visual Studio, you can use Nuget library called `Plog`

You can install it by right clicking the project name --> Manage NuGet packages ... --> then search `Plog`

I started to use this library last year, and it works like charm.
https://github.com/SergiusTheBest/plog